# Is it faster to merge and then sort, or sort and then merge?

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, sorting

I have 2 arrays which are not sorted. Would it be faster to sort them individually and then merge them? Or would it be faster to just concatenate the arrays first and sort the combined huge array?

Comment: Seems that second approach is faster, because concatenation is faster then merging.

Comment: I'd prefer to divide and conquer. Quick sort and merge sort benefit from it.

Comment: @Egor Sorting is a less linear operation than concatenation and merging (unless we're speaking about radix sort).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Could you please elaborate? Divide and conquer how exactly? Do you mean to sort the two arrays using quick sort and then use merge sort to put them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, big-O isn't really saying anything in this problem. Assuming the algorithm you are using is quicksort. [It has a average running time of:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Comparison_with_other_sorting_algorithms)

[image]

So now, if sort then merge we get:

f1 = 1.39n * log(n) * 2 + 2n

merge then sort:

f2 = n + 1.39 * 2n * log(2n)

The difference is

f2 - f1 = -n + 2.78n > 0

In the general case, if a sorting algorithm has complexity

C = k * nlog(n)

then since k should be normally bigger than 1, and isn't likely to be anywhere near 0.5, sort then merge will be faster if you are assuming the merge costs at most 2n.

Comment: I think it's not very meaningful to analyze the runtime of an algorithm in this way. The use of actual constants ignored by big-O notation suggests that it's more accurate, but you are still only counting selected operations (the number of comparisons, copying) and ignore many others (method calls, cache effects, etc.). IMO, if you want to perform analysis that is closer to reality than big-O, you should also account for all the system-/language-/implementation-specific constants and use a profiler instead.

Comment: @blubb You are definitely right; I forgot to put in my answer that this only compares the average number of comparisons when the input is random. The analysis above should definitely be extended, and the computational model be defined. I'll try to edit the answer to be more real-worldish instead of being just a highbrow nonsense later some time.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that concatenation is done in `O(1)`, merging takes `O(n)` and sorting `O(n log n)`, you have the choice between:

- sort and merge: `O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`
- concatenate and sort: `O(1) + O((2n) log (2n)) = O(n log n)`

therefore, asymptotically both options are equivalent.

Of course, the whole discussion is moot anyway if you **use MergeSort**.

Comment: I don't think concatenation will be `O(1)` in Java.

Comment: @assylias: that may well be. however, the argument remains valid as long as concatenation doesn't take more than `O(n log n)` operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that'll depend on the sorting algorithm and the size of your data.

But a wild guess is that merging and then sorting the whole lot is preferable. Because the merge in that case is just appending.

While in the other case you'll need to apply a sorting merge.

Comment: While your answer may be simpler to code, it is not faster which is what the question was asking for.

Comment: I think there's no definite answer until concrete code is run.

Answer (score 0):

When it is guaranteed that all entries in the 2nd array are larger than all in the 1st array, then you can concatenate the arrays after sorting each one. Every sorting algorithm has a complexity which is worse than linear, so when you can break down a sorting task into subsets which can be sorted individually, you should do it.

But when the entries need to be sorted again after merging the arrays, sorting each array beforehand is unlikely to make this any faster.

When you want to know it exactly, create a large set of test data and measure the performance yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the technique you are using.

Sort first and then merge would give you better results on a modern multi-processor architecture where you can run sorting algorithms on both arrays in parallel threads something around `O(nlogn)` (but with much lesser constant) and then merge them in `O(n)` time.